# Linux UBUNTU BASH - Goto a specific part of script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, random, ubuntu-14.04

I'm making a random number guessing game, but I want it to last longer than one guess, when u guess wrong it adds one to ded. and repeats from a certain point (I'll add STARTHERE where it needs to start again). I know theres a command in Windows with:

:hello
script
goto hello.

But this doesn't work in Ubuntu Bash. Here's my script.

```
number=$(( (RANDOM % 100)  + 1 ))

echo $number # Just for testing purposes
 # STARTHERE (This is not in the script)
read guess
if [ $guess = $number ];
then
echo "Cool! You won!"

elif [ $guess > $number ]
then
echo "not needed"

elif [ $guess < $number ]
then
echo "not needed rn"
fi

( & = 1 )
elif [ $guess =/= $number ]
then
ded=&((  (+ 1) ))

fi
```

Comment: Jumps/gotos are discouraged because they lead to spaghetti code. You could use a loop instead.

Comment: Can you reduce the example to the required minimum, as in remove all the comments and other fluff? It's just distracting (and also making the syntax invalid).

Comment: Nevermind, I just found out how loop worked. I thought it was a command put in the script and it loops the whole thing until it gets stopped somehow. Thanks, Socowi. -------- (Sorry, I'm new to BASH Scripting, as I'm only in Highschool)

Comment: See: 
 [GuessingGame/src/guess.bash](https://github.com/brendangregg/GuessingGame/blob/master/src/guess.bash)